# How to combine object with string to access member of object?

Tags: python

I'm looking inside of an object and wish to find all functions which I can potentially call.

This will not work:

```
for member in dir(MyObject):
    if callable(MyObject.member):
        print(member)
```

The error:

```
#  Error: AttributeError: file <maya console> line 2: 'MyObject' object has no attribute 'member' #
```

How can I concatenate `MyObject` and the value of `member` in the if condition?

Also, what is this kind of problem actually called?
I had issues coming up with a proper question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access an attribute dynamically, use `getattr`:

```
for member in dir(MyObject):
    if callable(getattr(MyObject, member)):
        print(member)
```